# how to host .net core 2.1 generic host in azure

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

Have several services written using the new generic Ihost in .NET CORE 2.1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1

I can't find any documentation on how to host these in Azure, I've tried hosting them in App Service but they don't seem to be recogniced as they don't start. How am I supposed to host these in Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way: 
**Write a docker file and host it as container**

Harder way: **Host it on VM**

AppService is designed for Owin or/and GlobalAsax composition root. You won't be able to run them without a **startup.cs** class